# How to throw TimeOutException in Hibernate when query takes more time?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, timeout

When my query sometimes takes more than 30 minutes to run. I want to throw timeoutQueryException

I'm using Hibernate 5.4.0 version  and using Java 1.8 to connect to Oracle 12c server

I am using this code block. I set timeOut but it is not work. When takes long time queries no other face exception I have to wait reponse

```
public List<EntityModel> search(EntityModel model) {
    List list = new ArrayList<EntityModel>();
    try {

        Criteria criteria = createCriteria(model);

        if (criteria != null) {
            int maxResults = PropertyUtil.getDBMaxResults();
            criteria.setMaxResults(maxResults);


            appendProjections(criteria);
            appendReadDescriptor(criteria);
            appendTransformer(criteria);
            criteria.setTimeout(10000);//setting 10 second but it is not work

            list = criteria.list();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` does only work if the server doesn't respond within that timeframe. As long as the query is still executing, the server has not timed out

Comment: @XtremeBaumer thanks,  I understand so, How can I define restriction of time on query

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible with hibernate. You might be able to restrict it on your database, though that would affect every query ever executed. As your queries run up to 30 minutes, you are probably able to change the query to reduce the execution time. [Docs on restricting query time](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/biee/BIEMG/GUID-3FD454F0-EBE3-4094-8ECB-F6F02F99267C.htm#dataaccess_limit4)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I find this, JPA 2 defines the javax.persistence.query.timeout hint to specify default timeout in milliseconds. Hibernate 3.5 (currently still in beta) will support this hint.
See also https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4662

Comment: I try to define queryHint like as http://apiwave.com/java/snippets/addition/javax.persistence.QueryHint

Comment: Again, this is not about the time the query takes to execute. This is all about establishing the connection

Answer (score 0):

```
@Transactional(timeout=10)
@Override
public List<EntityModel> search(EntityModel model) {

}
```

With spring transaction annotation is worked.